# How to Read or pick up a file (.txt or .req) from iPhone for Xcode Application development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, file

I'm developing an application using Xcode 10.1 Objective-C. I need to read a file (.txt or .req) from my iPhone Files app or current application file documents directory.

I'm able to set a file sharing options for my developing application in Xcode.

So is there is any APIs in Xcode Objective-C to read a file(.txt or .req) from my iPhone or current developing application file documents directory.

Comment: Just follow this steps - Open Xcode and Window - Device and simulator - select your application from the list - download it into your mac and extract it.

Comment: I already add the sample.txt file by connecting iPhone into iTunes and selected file sharing in iTunes and into my Application i added sample.txt file

Comment: now i need to read that file using Xcode development.

Comment: For that you have to know the stored path like as Document directory Path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code for reading a file from documents directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.txt"];
NSString *fileContent = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Comment: @Prithiv, If you need the content of your .req file as a string, yes, It will work